Laravel Redirect to the selected user from the dropdown after the action is done
Below is my controller that shows the users list in dropdown
public function show()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('layouts/regrid/show')->with('users', $users);
}

The following is the drop down using the above controller's users
<form class="col-12">
            <label>Select</label>
            <select class="form-control select2" id="user_id" style="width:262px !important">
               <option >Select</option> 
             @foreach ($users as $names)
              <option value="{{ $names->id }}">{{ $names->username }}</option>
              @endforeach 
             
            </select>
</form>

Now my issue is that when I select the user its data is shown which is ok but when I click the approve or disapprove the old selection is not retained and dropdown filter is removed showing all data instead of selected user data.
the controller method for approve is
public function approval($id)
    {
      // dd('kjhdkjehdeheh');
        $expence_data = AddExpence::find($id);

        $expence_data->update(['approved' => 1]);
        return redirect()->back();

    }

The jquery implementation for the api is
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('.select2').select2();
  var dropdown = $("#user_id");

  dropdown.on("change", function() {   
    var id = $(this).val();
    var updatedUrl =  "{{ url('api/show_data') }}/" + id; 
  
 

    // console.log(updatedUrl);

$('#expenceTable').data('url', updatedUrl);
// $('#expenceTable').bootstrapTable('refresh');
var locale = '{{ config('app.locale') }}';
var stickyHeaderOffsetY = 0;
var keyBlocked = function(key) {
            for(var j in blockedFields) {
                if (key === blockedFields[j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        var blockedFields = "searchable,sortable,switchable,title,visible,formatter,class".split(",");

$('.snipe-table').bootstrapTable('destroy').each(function () {
            data_export_options = $(this).attr('data-export-options');
            export_options = data_export_options ? JSON.parse(data_export_options) : {};
            export_options['htmlContent'] = false; // this is already the default; but let's be explicit about it
            export_options['jspdf']= {"orientation": "l"};
            // the following callback method is necessary to prevent XSS vulnerabilities
            // (this is taken from Bootstrap Tables's default wrapper around jQuery Table Export)
            export_options['onCellHtmlData'] = function (cell, rowIndex, colIndex, htmlData) {
                if (cell.is('th')) {
                    return cell.find('.th-inner').text()
                }
                return htmlData
            }
            $(this).bootstrapTable({
            classes: 'table table-responsive table-no-bordered',
            ajaxOptions: {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            },
            stickyHeader: true,
            locale: locale,
            stickyHeaderOffsetY: stickyHeaderOffsetY + 'px',
            undefinedText: '',
            iconsPrefix: 'fa',
            cookie: true,
            cookieExpire: '2y',
            mobileResponsive: true,
            maintainSelected: true,
            trimOnSearch: false,
            showSearchClearButton: true,
            paginationFirstText: "First",
            paginationLastText: "Last",
            paginationPreText: "Previous",
            paginationNextText: "Next",
            pageList: ['10','20', '30','50','100','150','200','500'],
            pageSize: 20,
            paginationVAlign: 'both',
            queryParams: function (params) {
                var newParams = {};
                for(var i in params) {
                    if(!keyBlocked(i)) { // only send the field if it's not in blockedFields
                        newParams[i] = params[i];
                    }
                }
                return newParams;
            },
            formatLoadingMessage: function () {
                return '<h2><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Loading... please wait.... </h4>';
            },
            icons: {
                advancedSearchIcon: 'fas fa-search-plus',
                paginationSwitchDown: 'fa-caret-square-o-down',
                paginationSwitchUp: 'fa-caret-square-o-up',
                fullscreen: 'fa-expand',
                columns: 'fa-columns',
                refresh: 'fas fa-sync-alt',
                export: 'fa-download',
                clearSearch: 'fa-times'
            },
                exportOptions: export_options,

            exportTypes: ['xlsx', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf','json', 'xml', 'txt', 'sql', 'doc' ],
            onLoadSuccess: function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); // Needed to attach tooltips after ajax call
            }

            });
        });
});
});


  </script>

Now issue how to retain the filter of dropdown and show that relevant data. When the user is selected following api's method is run
 public function index($id)
    {
        // $this->authorize('view', Category::class);
 
        // return 'hello';
        $expence_data = AddExpence::where('user_id' , $id )->first();
           // dd($expence_data);
            return response()->json($expence_data);
         //   return (new REgridTransformer)->transformgridUser($expence_data );


    }

I have tried to use the ajax request but it is not the requirement and also tried to redirect by sending the user id but not worked
